# express 4: headers on middleware are undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I have a simple middleware to get header token for validation, but headers are undefined;

My middleware:

```
const TokenMiddleware = async (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
    try {
        console.log(request.headers);
        //console.log('Request logged:', request.method, request.path)
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

But if call headers on route, give all.

Already tried `request.get('header-name')` and `request.header('header-name')` and could not get it.

Comment: your variable seems to be named 'req' not 'request'. So try 'req.headers'?

Comment: tanks, I ended up writing it wrong when posting. but is not a problem.

Comment: What are you passing as a parameter/body, can you please show your request object ?

Comment: Please show how this middleware is configured/called.  There is technically almost no difference between a middleware handler and a route handler so the only way your middleware doesn't work and your route handler does is if you have configured or specified them differently or wrongly.  We need to see that part of your code in order to be able to help.